# How does ActiveMQ detect slow consumer

Tags: activemq-classic

1. What is the exact logic ActiveMQ uses to say that a consumer is slow
   consumer?
2. In case of multiple consumers does slow take into account
       other consumers also connected to the same topic?

It will be great if code pointers to the same also can be provided

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at line 116 and the add method in [TopicSubscription.java](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/70875bd9468eb26505560894e142a03dba1193ee/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/TopicSubscription.java#L116).
2. A slow consumer is one slow consumer lacking behind in receiving published messages. How "fast" other consumers are does not matter for a slow consumer. It's more the difference between produced and consumed messages. Read the code for details or rephrase your question to something more specific.

Comment: Can we get an updated answer? The link does not work.

Comment: @IT_User of course. The answer is almost 10 years old though so.. for what it's worth the link is changed to github.